# I have been trying to write a below SQL query ande getting result as given below the query

Tags: sql

```
select
     TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.request_id,
     TRN_ADP_Stationary_Request.requester_name,
     item_id,   
    case when MONTH(TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.ITEM_QTY_TRADE_DATE)=6 then sum(item_qty_traded) else 0 end as JUNE,
    case when MONTH(TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.ITEM_QTY_TRADE_DATE)=7 then sum(item_qty_traded) else 0 end as JULY,
    case when MONTH(TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.ITEM_QTY_TRADE_DATE)=8 then sum(item_qty_traded) else 0 end as AUG

  from TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker
  join TRN_ADP_Stationary_Request
  on TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.request_id  =  TRN_ADP_Stationary_Request.stationary_request_id
  group by TRN_ADP_Stationary_Request.requester_name,item_id,
      MONTH(TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.ITEM_QTY_TRADE_DATE);
```

```
request requester item
_id      _name    _id    JUNE   JULY    AUG 
3   Prasad    150    2  0   0
3   Prasad    154    2  0   0
1   Sneha     150    15 0   0
1   Sneha     150    0  15  0
1   Sneha     150    0  0   6
1   Sneha   154 4   0   0
```

But here I want Result like:-

```
request_id  requester_name  item_id  JUNE  JULY  AUG 
1        Sneha      150      15     15    6
```

if 1st 3 columns data is same then then months data should be come in 1 row, as given above.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?

Comment: The point of question titles is to give a clear picture of the issue to potential answerers, and to make the same issue easily found by people with a similar problem. Please use a title that describes the problem, not the activity.

Answer (score 0):

you need to correct your GROUP_ID to have only three columns from your select

```
select
 TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.request_id,
 TRN_ADP_Stationary_Request.requester_name,
 item_id
```

from

```
group by TRN_ADP_Stationary_Request.requester_name,item_id,
  MONTH(TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.ITEM_QTY_TRADE_DATE)
```

Comment: still getting same result
my issue is how to merge these three rows

1   Sneha     150    15 0   0
1   Sneha     150    0  15  0
1   Sneha     150    0  0   6

result should be
1   Sneha     150    15  15  6

Comment: in group by clause only have these THREE columns from your select :

TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.request_id,
 TRN_ADP_Stationary_Request.requester_name,
 item_id

Answer (score 0):

Need to take out request_id column from select list.

```
select
         --TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.request_id,
         TRN_ADP_Stationary_Request.requester_name,
         item_id,   
        case when MONTH(TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.ITEM_QTY_TRADE_DATE)=6 then sum(item_qty_traded) else 0 end as JUNE,
        case when MONTH(TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.ITEM_QTY_TRADE_DATE)=7 then sum(item_qty_traded) else 0 end as JULY,
        case when MONTH(TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.ITEM_QTY_TRADE_DATE)=8 then sum(item_qty_traded) else 0 end as AUG

      from TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker
      join TRN_ADP_Stationary_Request
      on TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.request_id  =  TRN_ADP_Stationary_Request.stationary_request_id
      group by TRN_ADP_Stationary_Request.requester_name,item_id,
          MONTH(TRN_ADP_Items_Tracker.ITEM_QTY_TRADE_DATE);
```